# Fill up a sparse array with `undefined`

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I fill the empty slots of a sparse array with values (e.g. `undefined`)?

```
let array = ['a',,,,'z']

// Should return
['a', undefined, undefined, undefined, 'z']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will fill it up :

```
let array = ['a',,,,'z'];
Array.from(array);  
// Returns ['a', undefined, undefined, undefined, 'z']
```

Comment: Nice and clean, but spread syntax will be significantly more [performant](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/13243/0/arrayfrom-vs-forof-vs) than Array.from(). `[...array]`

Comment: @pilchard I get 1529 ops/sec for spread syntax and 1514 ops/sec for Array.from. I wouldn't call that "significantly" more performant. It's 0.7% better. Re-ran the tests a few times and the results were similar each time. The widest difference I got was 1536 ops/sec for spread syntax vs 1494 ops/sec for Array.from. Which is a 2.8% increase. I'd still hardly call it "significant".

Comment: @VLAZ I initially ran the benchmarks on Safari which shows a whopping 200% increase from Array.from to Spread. But in Chrome I get results closer to yours.

Comment: @VLAZ, which tests do you run and how do you run them, to get those numbers?

Comment: @BenDak the ones linked by pilchard : https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/13243/0/arrayfrom-vs-forof-vs scroll down and you'd see a "Run tests" button: https://i.imgur.com/9hvQNN8.png

Answer (score 1):

You can spread the array and you will get `undefined` in the previously empty slots

```js
let array = ['a',,,,'z']
const result = [...array];
console.log(result);
// ['a', undefined, undefined, undefined, 'z']

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  test("array ", array, i);
  test("result", result, i);
}

function test(name, arr, num) {
  console.log(`${num} in ${name}: ${num in arr}`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```